# LoadError: cannot load such file -- capybara Stand Alone Code

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, screen-scraping, html

I'm working on building a simple post miner using Ruby and the following tutorial (http://ngauthier.com/2014/06/scraping-the-web-with-ruby.html)

Here is my code I currently have:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

include Capybara::DSL
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist

visit "http://dilloncarter.com"

all(".posts .post ").each do |post|
    title = post.find("h1 a").text
    url   = post.find("h1 a")["href"]
    date  = post.find("a")["datetime"]
    summary = post.find("p.preview").text


    puts title
    puts url
    puts date
    puts summary
    puts " "

end
```

and i'm getting errors loading the gemfiles like the following:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- capybara
from /Users/dilloncarter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/dilloncarter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from WP_Miner.rb:3
from /Users/dilloncarter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

How can I get my gems to load properly?

Answer (score 5):

Have you installed `capybara` and `poltergeist`?

I just checked the tutorial you linked, and it doesn't seem to mention Gemfiles.
Also, if that is your script, you don't need a Gemfile.

All you need are the gems installed on your system and available in the ruby load path, and `require` will find them.

Try in a terminal:

```
$ gem list capybara
```

To see if it's installed.
If it isn't, install them both with:

```
$ gem install poltergeist
```

Capybara is a dependency of Poltergeist, and will be installed automatically.

Do that, and the script should work.

Answer (score 1):

Add poltergeist to your Gemfile
gem 'poltergeist'