# Can't run ruby automation file with cucumber - cannot load such file -- capybara (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, selenium, rubygems, cucumber, capybara

When I run **cucumber**, I get this error

> **cannot load such file -- capybara (LoadError)**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657046/loaderror-cannot-load-such-file-capybara-stand-alone-code) that's because i don't have poltergeist installed.

And if I run **gem install poltergeist**, I get

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
>       wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

If I run **gem list capybara**, I just get

> *** LOCAL GEMS ***

For last, this is what part of my env.rb file looks like

```
Learn more or give us feedback
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'capybara/cucumber'

$browser = ENV['browser'] ||:chrome
$browser = $browser.to_sym

$driver = ENV['driver'] || :selenium
$driver = $driver.to_sym

puts "Driver: #{$driver}"
puts "Browser: #{$browser}"

# For browser Firefox, geckodriver is required: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
# echo $PATH
# cd into geckodriver directory (probably Downloads) and extract from zip/tar
# mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/ (or whatever your $PATH is)
# Run Firefox with:
# cucumber /dir/some.feature driver=selenium browser=firefox

Capybara.default_driver = $driver

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => $browser,)
end

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {js_errors: false, phantomjs_options: ['--ssl-protocol=auto']})
    $platform = 'poltergeist'
end
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You don’t want or need Poltergeist anymore, it’s obsolete. Instead add capybara to your Gemfile, or if not using a Gemfile run `gem install capybara`. Also you should be doing `require ‘capybara/dsl`‘ instead of ‘require ‘capybara’`

See : https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/README.md#setup

Comment: Thanks Thomas. When I ran **gem install capybara**, I got this error thought - **ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)**

Comment: @WilfredoCasas If you can't run `gem install capybara` you have a bigger problem - that's a pretty basic ruby thing.  I'd say start by making sure you're running at least ruby 2.5 and make sure you're version of `gem` is up to date as well (`gem update --system`). Also if using rbenv you may need to run `rbenv rehash`

Comment: I created a new ticket for this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492452/cant-install-or-uninstall-anything-in-ubuntu-processing-was-halted-because-th