# Can't install or uninstall anything in Ubuntu - Processing was halted because there were too many errors

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to install and uninstall many different programs. For example:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ussp-push
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get purge ruby
```

And everytime I get this output in my terminal. This seems to have started after I tried installing MongoDB on my machine.

```
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-systemd:amd64
 grub-pc
 virtualbox-dkms
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 libssl1.1:amd64
 postgresql-common
 libdns-export1100
 openssl
 unattended-upgrades
 libdns1100:amd64
 mongodb-org-server
 bind9-host
 libisc169:amd64
 linux-headers-5.0.0-37-generic
 libisccc160:amd64
 libqt5network5:amd64
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04
 libqt5webkit5:amd64
 mongodb-org-shell
 libisc-export169:amd64
 qtbase5-dev:amd64
 libirs160:amd64
 libbind9-160:amd64
//etc
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error and this command helped me out

```
dpkg --configure -a
```